# Component identification from vintage tachometer

Tags: identification, automotive, tachometer

For the purpose of understanding how it works, I'm attempting to reverse-engineer the schematic of an analog gauge. For some context, it's an analog tachometer from the 70s, with a scale from 400 to 7000 rpm for a 4 cylinder engine.

I've come across this component on the picture below, with a package and markings I cannot identify. There are **two of them on the board** (you can see them next to each other), each with **3 terminals**. I'm thinking it might be a transistor, but the strange (to me) package confuses me a bit. The markings on the package are:

`V15
S10`

[image: Unknown component closeup]

I'm thinking the circuit might be similar to [this one from an earlier ('66) unit](http://forums.pelicanparts.com/porsche-911-technical-forum/266707-early-vdo-tachometer-guts-2.html), but without the thermistors.

**Update**: I traced the schematic, and I believe I could identify all parts except for the Zener (the 6.7V measured across it make me think it's a 6V8 one) and obviously the two components from this question (which I now believe to be transistors, though).

I can't make much sense of it yet and I need to double check it, but here it is:

[image: VDO analog tachometer schematic]

The input signal is from the (mechanical) distributor points of a classic vehicle without electronic ignition. It is a *periodic* waveform coming from output of the primary side of the ignition coil (low voltage side), and *each cycle* looks like the blue trace on this image:

[image: Ignition circuit waveform]

The maximum frequency of the signal is 233 Hz (7000 rpm), but in practice it would be less, as the vehicle's ECU would cut off the injection at a max of 5400 rpm (180 Hz).

Essentially, if I understand it correctly, the tachometer circuit should:

1. attenuate the input waveform to a low voltage signal
2. convert the signal to a square wave keeping its original frequency
3. convert the frequency to a voltage/current that is proportional to it
4. drive the tachometer needle's coil with that current

*Would someone have an idea what component it could be? Or perhaps which type of package it is?*

Comment: For a while that kind of package was not uncommon for a transistor. You could try partially reverse engineering a schematic or plug that thing into one of the eBay transistor testers?

Comment: If it has four terminals I'd go for "bridge rectifier". If three then it's probably a transistor. Extract and test.

Comment: Can you get us a different angle closeup on the part?

Comment: There is another one just to the left of it, looks three pin. Probably a transistor, maybe a double diode. Or something else!

Comment: @Transistor: thanks for the reply. It has three terminals. See the same component to the left of it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Yes, I think for now I'll see how far I get with reverse-engineering the schematic. Would you happen to know the name of that particular package?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, as mentioned, there is the same component next to the one marked. You can see it there from the other side. There is not much to it, really: 3 terminals, one side marked with a code, the other side unmarked. One of the top corners is beveled, the other one is at a right angle.

Comment: Transistor then, most likely. A diode tester will let you identify the base and whether it's NPN or PNP, Si or Ge. Then context (if it works, power it up and measure voltages; otherwise, what it's connected to) will let you distinguish collector and emitter. Unusual package ... what part of the world is it from?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, thanks. I think I'll go for the schematic route. Other than having restored the glass and enclosure (that's why I had to open it up), it's a working gauge, so I won't be unsoldering parts. It's a VDO tach, which comes from Germany, but they were shipped with VW, Audi and other makes all over the world.

Comment: I call them DIP3 package, no idea if anyone else does that too

Comment: https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_v1510p.html

Comment: @Janka, thanks, that looks promising. However, I'm not sure it's the same component. Looking up the [info on the manufacturer (Newmarket Transistors Ltd)](http://www.wylie.org.uk/technology/semics/Newmarket/Newmarket.htm) would seem to indicate that their packages for the V series (where "V" could probably stand for "Valve", even though these were solid-state) were metal cases. Also it seems that for their later devices they used the "NKT" marking.

Comment: I've now added the schematic to the question. I still need to study the schematic to understand it and check it out for mistakes. Also still to identify is the Zener diode's voltage. But I'm fairly certain by now that the unknown part is an NPN transistors. Thanks everyone!

Comment: These transistors you have there are hardly done by Newmarket Transistors Ltd, but by Valvo, Telefunken or Siemens. It wasn't (and isn't) uncommon for manufacturers to copy the specs of a common use transistor (and the V10, V15, V20 were common use back then) and put them into a package of their liking. It doesn't even have to be a Germanium transistor you have there, just one matching or overdoing the required specs.

Comment: @Janka, ah, thanks. I've tried to find more info on the specs for the V15, but other than the radiomuseum link you already posted, I've not found much. There is http://www.semicon-data.com/transistor/tc/bs/BSV15-6.html, but that's a PNP transistor, so I'll keep searching. In any case, you seem to know about the V15 transistors: if you'd feel like adding an answer with more info about them, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: That's what I wanted to tell you: manufacturers back then marked their own transistors as V15 to make them better marketable. So there is no more meaning than "PNP, better than the original specs" in this.

Comment: No worries, I had understood that. The bit that confused me was that the V15 is/was apparently a PNP transistor, whereas the ones on my circuit seem to be NPN. In any case, it seems I'll just to accept that they _are_ transistors, but their specs are probably not to be found.